# SQL select won't show the selected item

Tags: java, sql

When I run this code, why am I getting the last added record when selecting, and not the item from the box I selected?

```
String subj = null;
String sec = null;
String fac = null;

try {
    String tmp=(String) secCombo.getSelectedItem();
    String sql="select faculty,section,subject from facload where section=?";
    pst=(PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1,tmp);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
        sec = rs.getString("section");
        subj = rs.getString("subject");
        fac = rs.getString("faculty");
    }
} catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "prof  " +fac + "\n" + "subject  " + subj);
if (subCombo1.getSelectedItem().equals(fac) && subCombo.getSelectedItem().equals(subj)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "lalalala");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
while(rs.next()){
    sec = rs.getString("section");
    subj = rs.getString("subject");
    fac = rs.getString("faculty");
}
```

You are assigning the same variables again and again in your loop. After the loop finishes, they have whatever values they were set to in the last iteration.

Comment: sir what's the best way i can do to fix this?

Comment: Depends. Is your query only supposed to be returning one result? If so, maybe it's not specific enough.

Comment: yes sir one result only but i need that result to be the one i selected in my combo box. so that i cannot add again if they are both same

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have your database so I can't tell you why your query isn't returning the result you expect.

Comment: sir is there anyway that i can give you that information , so that you can help me ?